# Mimicking function Overriding in C

Tags: c

To be specific: Function overriding with the ability to call the base overridden methods.

There are two pieces to this. One is the pre-compiled library code (1), and the other is the User of the Library code (2). I'm implementing a smallest possible, classic Person and Employee example here.

Will highly appreciate a response from a hardcore C developer who knows OOP concepts. I'm developing both Library and User of the Library code, so I've control in both places.

**1 A) Library Code** (Pre-compiled)

**person.h**

```
typedef struct Person Person;

struct Person {
    char* name;
    void (*display)(const Person *self);
};

Person* PersonNew(char* name);
```

**person.c**

```
static void display(const Person *self) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", self->name);
}

Person* PersonNew(char* name) {
    Person* self = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    if(self == NULL) return NULL;

    self->name = strdup(name);
    self->display = display;

    return self;
}
```

**1 B)** Library can receive structs with composed Persons via pointers because it's library's responsibility to print these structs (therefore library doesn't know the existence of Employee struct)

```
void print(Person *person) {
     person->display(person); // problem, can only print name, no company
}
```

---

**2) The user of the Library Code**

**employee.h**

```
typedef struct Employee Employee;

struct Employee {
    Person super;
    char* company;
    void (*display)(const Employee *self);
};

Employee* EmployeeNew(char* name, char* company);
```

**employee.c**

```
static void display(const Employee *self) {
    self->super.display(&self->super); // re-use super display
    printf("Company: %s\n", self->company);
}

Employee* EmployeeNew(char* name char* company) {
    Employee* employee = malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    if(employee == NULL) return NULL;

    free(employee->super); // I also have memory leak issue.
    employee->super = *PersonNew(name); // library method to get struct with functions.
    employee->company = strdup(company);
    employee->display = display; // it's own version of display

    return employee;
}
```

**main.c**

```
Employee *employee = EmployeeNew("John", "Acme");
print(employee); // problem, calls base method, prints name only

// employee->display(); // works fine, but the requirement is somehow enable library code to be able to call employee version of display.
```

Comment: `*PersonNew(first, last)` leaks memory. `print(employee);` will result in a warning on most compilers.

Comment: adding `free(employee->super`, will that work?

Comment: No, it would not work. `super` is not a pointer.

Comment: so I guess I've these two problems. 1. to enable library call my overriden implementation and second deal with memory leak.

Comment: 1) You have to dissociate allocation and construction. 2) unless you have only one function, you should store a pointer to a function table rather than function pointers themselves.

Comment: Thanks @spectras, this is deep, I'm not as knowledgeable as you since I'm still learning, can you please write this in code, I'd understand it. Thanks again.

Comment: @spectras 2) I want to package functions in structs, I actually have many structs, and don't want to have tons of global functions all over. I know the language capability is limited, but how much can I push it.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to develop the comment into code :s. — For 1), I mean your construction functions should not allocate the object they construct, but take a pointer to allocated memory - this way they can be called by "subclasses" to construct their part in a larger struct. — For 2) google for "virtual method table", it's the technique used by most OO languages under the hood for virtual dispatching, it should give you nice pointers.

Comment: Thanks. I'll appreciate if you can get some time about 2). I went through virtual method table. Can you please help me with the code, I'm still not getting `constructor functions should not allocate the object they construct`, I've been struggling with this for quite some time.

Comment: or perhaps if you can share a link that talks about constructing without memory leak.

Comment: `I mean your construction functions should not allocate the object they construct, but take a pointer to allocated memory`, the constructor method does malloc the memory and initializes it, and returns the pointer. You mean I shouldn't initialize it and just malloc & return? I've separate Constructor for the subclasses btw. the question remains still, is it still leaking memory?

Comment: Hi Guys, just a quick question, how do you implement projects in real life/production in context of this question/answer, do you embed `Person super` or declare a pointer `Person *super` in your code with allocation. I'm coming from OOP working on a framework to be used by C developers, want to make them feel at home.

Comment: @AppDeveloper The former. Having the `Person` object embedded in `Employee` is precisely what legitimizes the cast of an `Employee*` to a `Person*` which, in turn, mimics the "*an employee is a kind of person*" relationship that is fundamental to inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and rather unsophisticated way to do it could be something like the following.

```
typedef struct Person Person;
typedef void (*DISPLAYPROC)(const Person* self);

struct Person {
    char* name;
    DISPLAYPROC display;
};

void ConstructPerson(Person* self, const char* name);
Person* NewPerson(const char* name);
void person_display(const Person* self);
```

```
void person_display(const Person* self) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", self->name);
}

void ConstructPerson(Person* self, const char* name)
{
    self->name = _strdup(name);
    self->display = person_display;
}

Person* NewPerson(const char* name) {
    Person* self = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    if (self == NULL) return NULL;

    ConstructPerson(self, name);
    return self;
}
```

```
void print(Person* person) {
    person->display(person); // dispatched at runtime to the right 'display'
}
```

```
typedef struct Employee Employee;

struct Employee {
    Person super;
    char* company;
};

void ConstructEmployee(Employee* self, const char* name, const char* company);
Employee* NewEmployee(const char* name, const char* company);
void employee_display(const Employee* self);
```

```
void employee_display(const Employee* self) {
    person_display((const Person*)self);
    printf("Company: %s\n", self->company);
}

void ConstructEmployee(Employee* self, const char* name, const char* company)
{
    ConstructPerson(&self->super, name);
    self->super.display = (DISPLAYPROC)employee_display;
    self->company = _strdup(company);
}

Employee* NewEmployee(const char* name, const char* company) {
    Employee* self = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    if (self == NULL) return NULL;

    ConstructEmployee(self, name, company);
    return self;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    Person* person = NewPerson("Bob");
    print(person); // calls person_display

    Employee* employee = NewEmployee("John", "Acme");
    print((Person*)employee); // calls employee_display

    free(person);
    free(employee);
}
```

A few notes:

- `Person` is embedded as a field (not a pointer) in `Employee` so that the casts are legal between `Person*` and `Employee*`;
- the `New/Construct` functions separate the initialization from the allocation, which was mentioned in the comments before.
- the `display` functions  are made visible (not static) so that a "derived" class can call the "base" function.

Left for the reader to fill in:

- `Destruct` functions paired with the `Construct` ones, so that the allocated strings get duly freed;
- separation of data initialization from "vtable" initialization, so that for example the `display` pointer is not initialized twice in `ConstructEmployee` (once in the nested `ConstructPerson` then overwritten immediately after in `ConstructEmployee`).

Comment: @AppDeveloper (i) It allows "derived" classes to call it e.g. `ConstructEmployee`. (ii) It allows for non-heap-based  objects e.g. `Employee bob; ConstructEmployee(&bob, "Bob", "Home")`.

Comment: I see, i pondered deep into left for reader notes (2) and noticed that you are re-using base class constructor in the derived class.

Comment: Thanks, I very much appreciate your answer, it gave me a very good direction, I'd say your solution is sophisticated. I filled in with the destructor function, can you please review my answer.

Comment: @AppDeveloper It still *is* unsophisticated. For just one example, consider an array of two pointers `Person *personOrEmployee[2];`. Even after adding `Destruct`, you can't clean it up without remembering the type of each pointer. Either that, or making `Destruct` "virtual" the same way `display` is. But once you do that the wishlist grows e.g. you'll also want a `Delete` paired with `New`, and you'll be on the slippery way to reinventing [vtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) and [C with classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront) ;-)

Comment: hi dxiv, please have a look at my comment under the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you put `Person` at the beginning of `Employee` hence there is no issue, but if you move to other location, it might lead to exception.

The `Employee` struct will look like:

```
struct Employee {
    char* name;
    void (*display)(const Person *self);
    char* company;
    void (*display)(const Employee *self);
};
```

Hence when you pass to `print`, since the `print` accepts only upper part of `Employee`:

```
struct Employee {
    char* name;
    void (*display)(const Person *self);
};
```

the call of `display` will redirect to `display` of `Person`. hence there is only `name` printing.

To override Person's display, let change these two structs to:

```
struct Person {
    void (*display)(const Person *self);
    char* name;
};

struct Employee {
    void (*display)(const Employee *self);
    Person super;
    char* company;
};
```

By moving all operands to beginning of struct, it will work -> but this is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Filling in Destruct function for the review only. Destruction of Derived class first before the Base class.

**employee.c**

```
void EmployeeDestruct(Employee *self) {
    free(self->company); // destruct derived first
    PersonDestruct(&self->super); // then destruct base
}
```

**person.c**

```
void PersonDestruct(Person *self) {
    free(self->name);
    // free(self); // removing since it'd fail badly for local stack vars
}
```

Comment: That will work (*), except `free(self);` doesn't belong there, since it would fail badly for local/stack variables that were not allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: I see, I'd remove `free(self)`, and only free all those variables that were allocated through `malloc`. updating.